# PostgreSQL: 'Collating' values from variable fields into a single result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Web application that allows two users to review an entry and then records them on a first-come, first-serve basis into one of two sets of fields in the (PostgreSQL 9.1) database. The relevant table looks like this (simplified a little obviously):

```
 name_1    | timestamp_1      | name_2 | timestamp_2
-----------+------------------+--------+------------------
 jane      | 2014-09-01 15:30 | (null) | (null)
 christine | 2014-09-01 12:00 | jane   | 2014-09-01 15:20
 mark      | 2014-09-02 10:20 | (null) | (null)
 mark      | 2014-09-02 10:30 | jane   | 2014-09-02 12:30
```

My goal is to create an activity report for each of the users (the ones in the `name_*` fields) which lists their name, the time stamp of their first review, the time stamp of their last review, and the total number of entries reviewed by that user. In table format, this is my expected output for the above data:

```
 name      | first            | last             | total
-----------+------------------+------------------+-------
 christine | 2014-09-01 12:00 | 2014-09-01 12:00 | 1
 jane      | 2014-09-01 15:20 | 2014-09-02 12:30 | 3
 mark      | 2014-09-02 10:20 | 2014-09-02 10:30 | 2
```

The reason i'm getting stuck is the fact that the name and the associated time stamp may appear in one of two fields (and which one it is can not be predicted). If i only cared about what `name_1` was doing that'd be fine, but i'm really struggling to figure out how to get one result from both sets of fields.

Any guidance as to how to complete this report?

I would also welcome any comments on the table schema itself; i am not sure having two sets of review fields was the optimal design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    name,
    min(timestamp) as first,
    max(timestamp) as last,
    count(*) as total
from (
    select name_1 as name, timestamp_1 as timestamp
    from t
    union all
    select name_2, timestamp_2
    from t
) s
group by name
```